# Awesome solution - Zoom H6 Handy Recorder

Tags: recorder, zoom-h6

[H6 Handy Recorder](https://zoomcorp.com/en/jp/news/)
Someone knows more information?[image]
<sub>(source: [zoom.co.jp](http://zoom.co.jp/img/text_img/text_img_3782.jpg))</sub>

Comment: it's too early to call this "awesome". it's definitely a unique approach, and i'm interested, but i'll need a lot more data before even a modest amount of gear lust kicks in.

Comment: i agree with shaun,it will lielly cost less than a single MKH416 so dont expect miracles

Answer (score 1):

I also would like to know if they've upgraded pres and if they have a better line level design. Think looks wild though! also, it's finally a viable interface rather than just a two in!

Answer (score 1):

A really interesting concept.  If the mic preamps are quiet enough then it should prove useful.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it'd be too expensive for the amateur, and too crazy for the pro :/ Also the buttons seems very limited, like menu navigation. However if the preamps are good, could be a winner.

Answer (score 0):

i think it looks like a frankenstein recorder. 
plastic housing, volume knobs on the mic's (!?).. 
this cannot be of very good construction quality. 
best thing is de dedicated rec level knobs and tracks buttons.

it could be useful for a novice recordist/student.
lot's of recording methods to choose from and learn to work with.

Answer (score 0):

A *very* quick hands-on with it.. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fuxzq20uduI
Seems less.. disposable than the H4.  The make or break will be the pricetag.

Answer (score 0):

It's a cool idea, but with that many options and channels I hope the price is fittingly high. If each mic capsule is built with quality then it might be a great add-on to our kits — here's to hoping each mic sounds like more than an H4n with a different polar pattern, otherwise I'd say Zoom will have wasted an opportunity. A quality analog limiter would be a good addition, too...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...I do like the slightly slanted meter display though...but I have a feeling it will be a "do-it-all-for-too-little" piece of kit. I certainly don't see myself "upgrading" from my Sony PCM M10.

Answer (score 0):

I did a small comparison between the H4n and the H6. The H6 seems to be a good value, but is definetly too big for me to carry around every day...
check the full comparison and audio previews here...
http://bit.ly/16mqT4R